# Android - Slide Up Panel (library) rounded corners

Tags: android, user-interface, slideup

I'm developing the app that should use Navigation drawer as a menu bur for better User Experience i decided to replace navigation drawer with slide up panel.

---

*My view is in this image*

---

[image]

---

Now i want to make this menu with rounded corners i used CardView with cornerRadius attribute but didn't work properly.

---

*This is my xml code for the sliding up panel*

```js
   <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:umanoPanelHeight="0dp"
        sothree:umanoShadowHeight="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/SlidingUpPanel">

   
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

The same design can be seen in Facebook messenger app:

---

[image]

---

*Any idea will be welcome,Thanks in advance...*

PS: The link of library that i use: [Github library](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)

Those who want all layout:

```js
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar" />


<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/SlidingUpPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="0dp"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#345D7D" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.33333">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/quran_icon" />

            </RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.33333">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="125dp"
                    android:layout_height="125dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/qibla_compass_icon" />

            </RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.33333">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/findMyLocation"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:src="@drawable/location_icon" />


            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.33333">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.33333">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.33333">

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>


</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 8):

Sliding up panel requires the attribute :

```js
sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
```

In order to overlay layouts.

---

By means of this attribute we not only can make panel **rounded** (With [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) ) but also set **transparent background** to slideuppanel.

*Reference*: [Github transparent background (Issues)](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/issues/4)

Answer (score 5):

> Create a new drawable resource like
>
> ```
> drawable_round_background.xml:
> ```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="16dp"
        android:topRightRadius="16dp"/>
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
</shape>
```

> And Set the `drawable_round_background.xml` as background to your sliding layout
>   like:

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:umanoPanelHeight="0dp"
    sothree:umanoShadowHeight="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/SlidingUpPanel">

   <!-- SLIDING LAYOUT -->
   <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_round_background">
   </LinearLayout>
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

hope this will help.

Comment: @TarlanAhadli can I see your whole layout.xml? because mine is working well.

Comment: did you also try to set a background to your recyclerview item layout? Since your recyclerview is the header of SlidingLayoutPanel.

Comment: No,i just want to make only menu of my app with rounded corners

Comment: yes my recyclerview own has its background color with the hex code of #345D7D,does it matter to my sliding up panel layout?

Comment: You must also use `app:umanoShadowHeight="0dp"` and `sothree:umanoOverlay="true"` in your `SlidingUpPanelLayout` view.

Comment: @dotGitignore, Thanks a lot. You self my time!